# How to run an instance of a parameterized fixture only against a certain test module?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

After spending quite some time trawling through documentation about parameterized fixtures, I was unable to figure out if it's possible to use a particular instance of a parameterized fixture only with a single test module.

My parametrized fixture inside my conftest.py below hits an API and gets a dictionary of devices to test against. I have separate test modules for different device types (rr, cr, bdr and pe).

When I tried to run my code as is, it used every instance of the parameterised fixture against all test modules which is not what I wanted.

Is it possible to use an instance of my fixture i.e. request.params=rr only for the rr test module? Or would I have to copy and paste the fixture into each test module instead and then change the one parameter?

```
@pytest.fixture(params=["rr", "cr", "bdr", "pe"], scope="session", autouse=True)
def pytestnr(request):
    # Initalise nornir
    pytestnr = InitNornir(
        inventory={
            "plugin": "NetBoxInventory2",
            "options": {
                "nb_url": my_secrets["netbox_url"],
                "nb_token": my_secrets["netbox_token"],
                "ssl_verify": False,
                "use_platform_napalm_driver": True,
            },
        },
        logging={"enabled": False},
    )
    pytestnr = pytestnr.filter(F(name__contains=request.param))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use some parameters' mapping in your fixture depending on module that you came from.

For instance, define `dict` mapping and autouse `module` scoped fixture in your `conftest.py` like this:

```
PARAM_MAPPING = {
    "test_module_1_1.py": "param_for_module_1_1",
    "test_module_1_2.py": "param_for_module_1_2",
    "test_module_2_1.py": "param_for_module_2_1"
}

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="module")
def global_module_fixture(request):
    print(f"\nglobal module {request.node.name} setup")
    param = PARAM_MAPPING.get(request.node.name)
    if param:
        print(f"Some actions with {param}")
    else:
        print(f"No actions for {request.node.name}")
```

This way you can access desired params in different modules and ignore params that are not specified in your `PARAM_MAPPING`.

`request.node.name` in `module` scoped fixture contains module name.

I have following structure:

```
tests/
├─ conftest.py
├─ test_package_1/
│  ├─ test_module_1_1.py
│  ├─ test_module_1_2.py
├─ test_package_2/
│  ├─ test_module_2_1.py
│  ├─ test_module_2_2.py
```

And following output:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 16 items

test_package_1\test_module_1_1.py::TestClass111::test_1111 
test_package_1\test_module_1_1.py::TestClass111::test_1112 
test_package_1\test_module_1_1.py::TestClass112::test_1121 
test_package_1\test_module_1_1.py::TestClass112::test_1122 
test_package_1\test_module_1_2.py::TestClass121::test_1211 
test_package_1\test_module_1_2.py::TestClass122::test_1222 
test_package_2\test_module_2_1.py::TestClass211::test_2111
test_package_2\test_module_2_2.py::TestClass221::test_2211


global module test_module_1_1.py setup
Some actions with param_for_module_1_1

PASSED tests/test_package_1/test_module_1_1.py::TestClass111::test_1111
PASSED tests/test_package_1/test_module_1_1.py::TestClass111::test_1112
PASSED tests/test_package_1/test_module_1_1.py::TestClass112::test_1121
PASSED tests/test_package_1/test_module_1_1.py::TestClass112::test_1122

global module test_module_1_2.py setup
Some actions with param_for_module_1_2

PASSED tests/test_package_1/test_module_1_2.py::TestClass121::test_1211
PASSED tests/test_package_1/test_module_1_2.py::TestClass121::test_1212
PASSED tests/test_package_1/test_module_1_2.py::TestClass122::test_1221
PASSED tests/test_package_1/test_module_1_2.py::TestClass122::test_1222

global module test_module_2_1.py setup
Some actions with param_for_module_2_1

PASSED tests/test_package_2/test_module_2_1.py::TestClass211::test_2111
PASSED tests/test_package_2/test_module_2_1.py::TestClass211::test_2112
PASSED tests/test_package_2/test_module_2_1.py::TestClass212::test_2121
PASSED tests/test_package_2/test_module_2_1.py::TestClass212::test_2122

global module test_module_2_2.py setup
No actions for test_module_2_2.py
PASSED tests/test_package_2/test_module_2_2.py::TestClass221::test_2211
PASSED tests/test_package_2/test_module_2_2.py::TestClass221::test_2212
PASSED tests/test_package_2/test_module_2_2.py::TestClass222::test_2221
PASSED tests/test_package_2/test_module_2_2.py::TestClass222::test_2222
```

As you can see, I have defined some params for modules `1_1`, `1_2` and `2_1` and left `2_2` without any value. So setup was performed for every module, however `2_2` had no actions (since it went to `else` block).

You can use this code as a reference. I believe this solution should cover desired behavior in your case.